# OutputStream as interface

Tags: java, interface, io

Why is `java.io.OutputStream` not modeled as an interface instead of abstract class?

An interface can prove useful for example unit testing, I thought.

Comment: Well, you can always unit test using a mocking library

Comment: Mockito does provide a way to test abstract class i.e. spy. But spy(s) require you to provide a concrete implementation which is not not considered as clean.

Comment: Well, maybe, but sometimes you do not have a choice... Anyway, this is a little offtopic for your particular question ;)

Comment: Would like to correct myself. It seems jmock provides some extensions (ClassImposteriser) to mock abstract class properly.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the methods are already implemented. This is not possible for Interfaces.

```
close() 
void flush() 
void write(byte[] b) 
void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
```

Are already implemented with a default implementation.

Comment: They could have easily made an interface and an abstract class

Comment: @Steve Kuo: Often it would be nice to have both, but sadly SUN often decided not to make it this way ;-(

Comment: Yes looks so. They overlooked a design choice that probably wasn't relevant at that time?

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc gives a hint:

> Applications that need to define a subclass of OutputStream must always provide at least a method that writes one byte of output.

(that is, `void write(int b) throws IOException`)

If you look at its actual code, the default other `write()` methods of this base abstract class use the sole method you need to implement.

Also, output streams may not be linked to an actual resource (`ByteArrayOutputStream` for instance): this class therefore also has default implementations for `.close()` and `.flush()` which do nothing, and which need to be overriden only by streams having an actual resource behind them.

As for testing purposes, the only difference for unit testing is really that you need to `extends` rather than `implements`, and not forget to override the methods you need. Or use a mocking library (such as mockito, or jmock, or...).

Comment: Although, Java could have achieved same with a InputStream interace and a AbstractInputStreamBase. 

Jmock does provide sufficient extensions to mock abstract class consistent to mocking an interface. Thanks for pointer.

Comment: Yes, of course, but is it really worth it? Interfaces are all good all well, but abusing them can lead to code which is more complicated than what it could be otherwise. Matter of taste, probably!

Comment: What I could conclude so far is current InputStream is now a legacy class we have to deal with. It has been present since Jdk 1.0 that was released in 1996. Not sure how mainstream current unit testing practices were back then.

Answer (score 2):

In fact,  java.io.OutputStream  (the same to java.io.InputStream) uses the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Relate to the question, here is the response taken from ([Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) page 93):

> The point is that **it’s vital that the decorators have the same type
>   as the objects they are going to decorate**. So here we’re using
>   inheritance to achieve the type matching, but we aren’t using
>   inheritance to get behavior.
>
> So that's why we prefer Inheritance (AbstracClass) over Interface
>   (Polymophism) in this case. But note that, in most of the other cases,
>   the principe is inverse: "**Favor composition (interface) over
>   inheritance (abstract class)**".

[image]

Comment: Type matching can be achieved using interface too? See the Java examples in Decorator pattern's Wikipedia page for some illustrations.

Comment: Yes, but what we need here is a skeletal implementation. Interfaces are not permitted to have method implementations, In some cases, we need an abstract skeletal implementation class. This is also the idea behind the Java Collection Framework (as explained by Joshua Bloch in his book Effective Java, item 18: Prefer interfaces to abstract classes)

Comment: The argument was why not have a InputStream interface along with AbstractInputStreamBase (the skeletal impl). (Collections are rather a good example of interface driven design.)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably an abstract class because all but one of its methods are concrete (implemented)... And you can subclass it whenever you need something else (for testing), or you can mock it as well it in some test situations...

Answer (score 0):

It's made as abstract class, so it could be treated as interface.

Regarding the `OutputStream` unlike an `interface` the class provides default implementation for method `write`.

Comment: and whats the advantage of having an abstract class rather than an interface ?#

Comment: Advantage of an abstract class: some methods can already be implemented. Disadvantage: you cannot extend more than one class but implement more than one interface.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: before Java 8 (not yet final) you could not implement methods in interfaces, so the advantage is that you can implement (some of) the methods.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: That's what I said: http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-are-default-methods/

Comment: @pgras then tahts what i asked for a  link ... thanks dude/dudette  :)

Comment: @MrSmith42 You can always have an abstract class that implements an interface